# Deploy ASP.NET Web API in Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, jakarta-ee, .net-core

I'm a .NET developer, I want to develop an ASP.NET Web API that will be deployed on ubuntu and will be called by a J2EE application.
is that what I would have deploying problems on ubuntu?

do you think that ASP.NET Web API is a good choice? or should I develop my API in ASP.NET CORE?

thanks.

Comment: It must be Core

Comment: no way with asp.net web ?

Comment: Nope because we only have .NET Core for linux

Comment: The .NET Framework does not run on Linux (unless you count Mono). .NET Core is support on Linux, and Web API is available for .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose Asp.Net Core over Asp.Net . 
You can not deploy asp.net web api application to ubuntu, but you can with asp.net core web api.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to go for asp.net core for linux platform. You can deploy this with the help of docker as well.